# Excel VBA: What am I missing in this simple OFFSET?

Tags: vba, excel, offset

Code finds the header row and correct column.  I want to execute some code on the range starting one cell under the header row in the same column and down to the last row in the same column.  I've tried to use `offset` to create the range but the `offset` fails every time. Can `offset` not be used this way?

```
Sub Del_Y_Rows()
Dim Rng, fcell, LastRow, SrchRng, sRNG, eRNG As Range
Dim Findstring As String
Findstring = "Header"

With Sheets("thisSheet")
   Set SrchRng = .Range("a1:l15")
   Set fcell = SrchRng.Find(What:=Findstring, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            MatchCase:=False)
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, fcell.Column - 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print "fcell " & fcell.Address

    sRNG = .Range(fcell).Offset(1, 0)   'this fails  'sRng = start of the range
    Debug.Print "srng " & sRNG
    eRng = .cells(LastRow, fcell.Column)  'eRng = end of the range
    Rng = .Range(sRNG, eRng)
    Debug.Print "rng is " & Rng.Address
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Test whether `fcell Is Nothing`. BTW, only `eRNG` is a `Range`. You have the rest declared implicitly as `Variant`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fcell` is a range and the `RAnge()` is not needed:

```
sRNG = fcell.Offset(1, 0)
```

One more thing, You will want to use a check to make sure the fcell is actually a range and not nothing.

```
Sub Del_Y_Rows()
Dim Rng As Range, fcell As Range, LastRow as Long , SrchRng As Range, sRNG As Range, eRNG As Range
Dim Findstring As String
Findstring = "Header"

With Sheets("thisSheet")
   Set SrchRng = .Range("a1:l15")
   Set fcell = SrchRng.Find(What:=Findstring, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            MatchCase:=False)
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, fcell.Column - 2).End(xlUp).Row
    If not fcell is nothing then

        Debug.Print "fcell " & fcell.Address

        set sRNG = fcell.Offset(1, 0)   'this fails  'sRng = start of the range
        Debug.Print "srng " & sRNG
        set eRng = .cells(LastRow, fcell.Column)  'eRng = end of the range
        set Rng = .Range(sRNG, eRng)
        Debug.Print "rng is " & Rng.Address
   End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use Set for objects.

Set sRNG = .Range(fcell).Offset(1, 0)